# Stop FancyTree checkbox lines from being highlighted as active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selected, fancytree

In checkbox multi select mode, how can I stop [FancyTree](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Dynamic-Tree-View-Plugin-Fancytree/demo/) lines that have been checked from being highlighted with a background color?

I find the default Win 7 theme (and most other themes) style behaviour confusing because both the possibly **unchecked** current active line and the many **checked** lines all have the same blue background.
The usability issue here is that the collection of highlighted lines (with a blue background) may represent **both** checked lines and also represent the current active line which may not be checked. This will lead to user mistakes. Only the XP theme behaves sanely but doesn't look as good.

What is the simple CSS I can tweak to make any theme operate so that the checked lines have no color background at all, and only the active (currently clicked on) line has a background colour highlight?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the css rule of node selection like this:

```
.fancytree-treefocus span.fancytree-selected .fancytree-title, span.fancytree-selected .fancytree-title{
    background: transparent;
}
```